# iOS: How do I keep a UIImageView from resetting after a scoring update?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

The game I'm trying to make is simple enough.  A UIImageView fireball falls from the top of the screen, and the touch screen is used to move the other UIImageView Dustin to avoid it.

Once the fireball reaches the bottom of the screen, it resets back to the top, and the user's score increases by 1.  The problem is that after I added the scoring functions, the Dustin UIImage resets to its original position after the fireball reaches the bottom.  Without the scoring method, Dustin's image doesn't reset.  How does the scoring cause my imageview's position to reset?  Most of my code from the ViewController is below.

```
int theScore;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self initializeTimer];
}

- (void)updateScore {
    theScore = theScore + 1;

    _score.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",theScore];
}

- (void) initializeTimer {
    if(theTimer == nil)
    {
        theTimer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(gameLogic:)];
    }

    theTimer.frameInterval = 1;
    [theTimer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void) gameLogic:(CADisplayLink *) theTimer {
    if(!CGRectIntersectsRect(_fireball.frame, _Dustin.frame)){
        if(_fireball.center.y >600){
            _fireball.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);

            [self updateScore];
        }

        _fireball.center = CGPointMake(_fireball.center.x, _fireball.center.y+4);
    }
    else{
        }
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    _firstTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    _lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    _Dustin.center = CGPointMake(_firstTouch.x, _Dustin.center.y);
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    _firstTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    _lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    _Dustin.center = CGPointMake(_firstTouch.x, _Dustin.center.y);
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    _firstTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    _lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    _Dustin.center = CGPointMake(_firstTouch.x, _Dustin.center.y);
}
```

Comment: Do you have autolayout enabled? Changing the score might cause the view it is in to use autolayout, resetting the 'Dustin' object to it's original place.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  That fixed the issue.